# Secondary replica database file location in Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I inherit a setup of two nodes (primary & secondary replica) Availability Group.

On my secondary replica node, the SQL server instance default files are stored at:

[image]

My default primary replica node  files are as follow:

[image]

When I look at the synchronizing database's properties on my secondary replica, I see its database files as follow

[image]

They are primary replica node directories.  Is this how it works in Availability Group?

That is when you look at the file group of your secondary replica database, they show the paths of the primary replica database even though the data file and log file are stored at a different local directory?

Comment: Those are default locations, they may not be the actual file locations, I would look at each databases file properties to see where the files actually are.

Comment: And read the recommendation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/manually-prepare-a-secondary-database-for-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Recommendations

Comment: Thanks James & David.  If I have my choice I'd make both nodes having the same disk drive and that's what I'm trying to figure out with this question.  In the secondary node when I look at the database file under the properties it points to G: and H: but those drive do not exist on my secondary node.  That is why I assume it just show what is on the primary replica and not the actual path of the database.

Comment: You or your server support team should be able to rename the drives.  You will want to practice on a non-prod system.  If your using virutual servers, it might be easier to build two new servers correctly, add them to the AG, and then fail over to the new better servers and retire the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try and open the database properties window on a secondary replica, SSMS will throw you an error, so my guess is that you're not actually connected to the secondary replia when you're checking these paths.

Run the following on both nodes:

```
select db_name(database_id), name, physical_name
from sys.master_files
```

This will show you the physical paths that SQL Server is using to access each file, and I would expect will show you different paths on each replica.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me verify my assumption in my question.  When I ran the script on the secondary replica database, it shows all my data file and log files on L: and K.  However, when I right click on the actual database under the object explorer, it shows the files are at G: and H which aren't the file path of the secondary replica node but instead the primary replica node.